# Semantic Similarity across multiple languages

Tags: nlp, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am using word embeddings for finding similarity between two sentences. Using word2vec, I also get a similarity measure if one sentence is in English and the other one in Dutch (though not very good).

So I started wondering if it's possible to compute the similarity between two sentences in two different languages (without an explicit translation), especially if the languages have some similarities (Englis/Dutch)?

Comment: See also '**update**' just added to bottom of my answer.

Comment: @gojomo will follow up on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume that your sentence-similarity scheme uses only word-vectors as an input – as in simple word-vector averaging schemes, or Word Mover's Distance.

It should be possible to do what you've suggested, provided that:

- you have good sets of word-vectors for each language's words
- the coordinate spaces of the word-vectors are compatible, meaning the words for the exact-same things in both languages have nearly-identical coordinates (and other words with similar meanings have close coordinates)

That second quality is not automatically assured. In fact, given the random initialization of word2vec models, and other randomization introduced by the algorithm/implementation, even subsequent training runs on the exact same data won't place words into the exact same places. So word-vectors trained on totally-separate English/Dutch corpuses won't likely place equivalent words at the same coordinates.

But, you can learn an algebraic-transformation between two spaces, based on certain anchor/reference word-pairs (that you know should have similar vectors). You can then apply that transformation to all words in one of the two sets, which results in you having vectors for those 'foreign' words within the comparable coordinate-space of the 'canonical' word-set.

In fact this very idea was used in one of the first word2vec papers:

"[Exploiting Similarities among Languages for Machine Translation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4168)"

If you were to apply a similar transformation on one of your language word-vector sets, then use those transformed vectors as inputs to your sentence-vector scheme, those sentence-vectors would likely have some useful comparability to sentence-vectors in the other language, bootstrapped from word-vectors in the same coordinate-space.

**Update:** There's a very interesting [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02502) that manages to train word-vectors in multiple languages simultaneously, using a corpus that includes both raw sentences in each single language, and a (smaller) set of aligned-sentences that are known to mean the same in both languages. Gensim doesn't yet support this mode, but there's [discussion of supporting it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gensim/zksGwKHnIUA/7lde13FbAgAJ) in a future refactor.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently produced a Python implementation of the technique mentioned in the paper from @gojomo's answer: [transvec](https://pypi.org/project/transvec/).

You'll need to provide word translation pairs as training data (I just threw words from my corpus into Google Translate to get as many such pairs as I can) and then you can use a wrapper model from `transvec` to produce comparable word embeddings for multiple languages. Here's an example:

```
import gensim.downloader
from transvec.transformers import TranslationWordVectorizer

# Pretrained models in two different languages.
ru_model = gensim.downloader.load("word2vec-ruscorpora-300")
en_model = gensim.downloader.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300")

# Training data: pairs of English words with their Russian translations.
# The more you can provide, the better.
train = [
    ("king", "царь_NOUN"), ("tsar", "царь_NOUN"),
    ("man", "мужчина_NOUN"), ("woman", "женщина_NOUN")
]

bilingual_model = TranslationWordVectorizer(en_model, ru_model).fit(train)

# Find words with similar meanings across both languages.
bilingual_model.similar_by_word("царица_NOUN", 1) # "queen"
# [('king', 0.7763221263885498)]
```

Don't worry about the weird POS tags on the Russian words - this is just a quirk of the particular pre-trained model I used.

For the case of documents rather than words, things are a little trickier because Doc2Vec can't use pre-trained Word2Vec models as a starting point. However, you can get an approximate document vector by simply taking the mean of all the word vectors from that document. If you provide a 2d array to `TranslationWordVectorizer`'s `transform` method, it will do exactly this and provide you with an approximate document vector so you can find documents with similar meaning even if the languages are different.