# Calculate Cross-Lingual Phrase Similarity (using e.g., MUSE and Gensim)

Tags: python, nlp, multilingual, gensim, word-embedding

I am new to NLP and Word Embeddings and still need to learn many concepts within these topics, so any pointers would be appreciated. This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571295/semantic-similarity-across-multiple-languages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233632/word2vec-gensim-multiple-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1), and I think there may have been developments since these questions had been asked. Facebook [MUSE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04087.pdf) provides aligned, supervised [word embeddings for 30 languages](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE#multilingual-word-embeddings), and it can be used to calculate word similarity across different languages. As far as I understand, The embeddings provided by MUSE satisfy the requirement of [coordinate space compatibilty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571295/semantic-similarity-across-multiple-languages). It seems that it is possible to [load these embeddings into libraries such as Gensim](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20071/how-do-i-load-fasttext-pretrained-model-with-gensim), but I wonder:

1. Is it possible to load multiple-language word embeddings 
   into Gensim (or other libraries), and if so:
2. What type of similarity measure
   might fit in this use case?
3. How to use these loaded word embeddings
   to calculate cross-lingual similarity score of phrases* instead of
   words?

*e.g., "*ÖPNV*" in German vs "*Trasporto pubblico locale*" in Italian for the English term "*Public Transport*".

I am open o any implementation (libraries/languages/embeddings) though I may need some time to learn this topic. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm learning MUSE and very confused. Cud you plz share the code of this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite usual to average multiple word embeddings to get a phrase or sentence representation. After all, this is exactly what FastText does by default when it is used for sentence classification.

You can, of course, load as many word-embeddings sets in Gensim, but you would need to implement the cross-lingual comparison yourself. You can the vector just using the square bracket notation:

```py
model = gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model('your_path')
vector = model['computer']
```

Just use cosine similarity for comparing the vector. If you don't want to write it yourself, use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html).

Comment: Hi @Jindřich, I really appreciate your quick reply. I would like to confirm my understanding from your answer - so here are the rough steps: 1. Load the FastText word embedding for say, German language via Gensim; 2. Get the vector representations of each word within a particular German phrase 3. Get the average value from these word vectors from step 2 to obtain the phrase's vector representation 4. Repeat steps 1-3 for, say, Italian and 5)  Calculate the similarity using Cosine. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Averaging all the words of a text together, to get a single summary vector for the text, then comparing that summary vector to other text vectors is one fast & simple approach, as described in @Jindřich's answer.

If Facebook has ensured these vectors are "in the same coordinate space", then individual words, or the averages of runs-of-words (phrases/sentences/etc), can be compared using typical cosine-similarity – even across languages.

But, there are other more-sophisticated ways to compare runs-of-words, when you're starting from word-vectors, that might provide a more fine-grained measure than plain average-comparisons. For example, "Word Mover's Distance" uses the full set of each text's set-of-word-vectors, rather than a single summary vector, as input.

It's quite a bit more expensive to calculate, however, especially on longer texts – because it's essentially searching for a minimal set of transitions that "move" the "piles of meaning" in one text (as represented by its word's positions in vector-space) to match the other text.

It's available in `gensim` as the function `wmdistance` on any set of `KeyedVector`-style word-vectors, but it assumes both your texts draw their vectors from the same set-of-vectors. You'd have to adapt the code to draw from two different vector-sets, or somehow merge the two-languages vectors into a single `KeyedVectors`.

Comment: Thank you @gojomo for confirming the word-vector averaging approach, as well as suggesting the more sophisticated approach. Adapting the code to draw from two different vector-sets seems to require more understanding within Gensim's implementation, but merging two languages into one single KeyedVectors sounds more practical. By merge, do you mean simply append the two word-vectors model as implemented in [this method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.BaseKeyedVectors.add)? If not, how the merge can be properly done?

Comment: There's no built-in support for a smart merge, but the `add()` method you've linked could work. It might not handle word-collisions (same token, different meaning in each language) very well. (For that, you might want to change every word in each relevant language to include a language suffix, eg `'report/en'`, `'report/fr'`, etc.– both when appending them all into the same `KeyedVectors`, and then again when looking up or comparing texts in a known language.)